# Bijection between the domain of a map and the coproduct of its preimage

Tags: set-theory

I encounter this problem:

Suppose $f$ is a mapping from set $A$ to set $B$. Show that a bijection exists between $A$ and $\amalg_{b\in B}f^{-1}(b)$.

What confuses me is that since the coproduct of the preimage is simply the domain $A$, then isn't the identity map in $A$ the bijeciton? Am I missing something, or is this problem really so simple?

Comment: Well, you are right, as $f^{-1}(b)$ are disjoint, their disjoint union is isomorphic to their union, which is $A$.

Comment: The identity map is not the bijection, but only because the disjoint union is a distinct object from the union. It depends on exactly how the disjoint union is defined in your source, but most commonly $$\amalg_{b\in B}f^{-1}(b) = \{\big(a, f^{-1}(f(a))\big) \mid a \in A\}$$ which is not the same set as $A$ itself.